# Calling one function inside another, does not execute as desired

Tags: c

Since I've had several members tell me to post the whole program I'm gonna post the whole program so you can exectue it.

In this program I want to be able to register car parts and change the inventory balance.

Now to the issue. Every function itself worsk well, the problem starts when I call searchIt() function to changeIn() function. I need searchIt() so I can search the item before modifying its inventory balance.

Issues:

1. Whenever I serach for an item and change inventory on that item, it changes on every item.
2. In menu if I choose (3)change inventory balance and then serach for an item that does not exist it does not tell me "Wrong item number" instead it exits the program.
3. The inventory balance goes to negative numbers.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXELENGTH 20
#define MAX 100

struct car{

    int itemNmr;
    char name[MAXELENGTH];
    int inventory;
};
typedef struct car Car;

void registerArticle(Car a[], int *pN);
void print(Car a[], int n);
void changeIn(Car a[], int n);
int searchIt(Car a[], int n);


Car createIt(int itemNmr, char name[],int inventory){

    Car c;
    c.itemNmr = itemNmr;
    strcpy(c.name, name);
    c.inventory = inventory;
    return c;
}

int main(){


    Car reg[MAX]; 
    int choice;
    int nrOfIt=0; 

    while(1){
        printf("(1)Register new pars\n(2)Display all parts\n(3)Change inventory\n(4)Search\n(5)Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
                case 1: registerArticle(reg, &nrOfIt);
                        break;
                case 2: print(reg,nrOfIt);
                        break;
                case 3: changeIn(reg,nrOfIt);
                        break;
                case 4: searchIt(reg,nrOfIt);
                        break;
                case 5: printf("Exit");
                        return 0;
                default: printf("Try again!");
                        break;
        }
    } return 0;
}

void registerArticle(Car a[], int *pN){

    int inventory;
    int itemNmr;
    char name[MAXELENGTH]; 

    while(1){

        printf("Item number(0 to exit): ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &itemNmr);
        
        if(itemNmr==0){
            return;
        }
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s%*c", name);
        printf("Inventory: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &inventory);
        a[*pN]=createIt(itemNmr,name,inventory);
        (*pN)++;   
    }
}

void print(Car a[], int n){

    if(n==0){
        printf("the list is empty\n");
    }else{
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", a[i].itemNmr, a[i].name, a[i].inventory);
       }
       return;
    }
}

int searchIt(Car a[], int n){
    
    while(1){

        int itemN;          
        printf("Type item number: ");
        scanf("%d", &itemN);
        if(itemN==0){
            break;
        }
        int found =0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
          if(itemN==a[i].itemNmr)
          {                                           
              printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\n", a[i].itemNmr, a[i].name, a[i].inventory);
              return i;                         
              break;                   
          }                   
       }
         if(!found)
         {
         printf("Wrong item number!");
         }
}
    return 0;
}

void changeIn(Car a[], int n){

        int input;
        int i;
        searchIt(a,i);
     
        printf("Increase or decrease by: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);
 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i].inventory += input;

        if(a[i].inventory<0)
            a[i].inventory = 0;       
}
       ```
````

Comment: `searchIt` is supposed to be passed the array and the number of elements `n`. In the `changeIn` function, you instead pass `i` for the second parameter, which is an uninitialized value. Your program will not behave correctly. But let's say by sheer luck, it finds something and doesn't crash. Well, then your `changeIn` function ignores the index returned by `searchIt`, and instead loops through all your cars and updates the `inventory` for each one. You need to take a step back and carefully read every line of code here. It should not be surprising that you're seeing these issues.

Comment: Your functions have to do 2 very different things: they read something from the user, and then perform an action on an array.  Per the single concern princip, you should separate those. That way you could have a function that searches for an item and returns its index and a function that updates the inventory balance for a item knowing its index.

Comment: @paddy understood, thanks. I changed that and now it tells me if I enter wrong item number but still changes invetory balance of all items. And also balance stops at 0 and does not go to negative nubmers, so that a good thing.

Comment: Okay, do you see this code you wrote: `for(i=0;i<n;i++) a[i].inventory += input;` ... what _exactly_ do you think it does? I have a feeling that your general bewilderment about your own code's behavior might stem from not understanding it in the first place.

Comment: That was my thought that it might be wrong, as i commented to @unwind below. If I understand it goes through array one by one and adds input to every each of them?

Comment: Correct, and how do you think that relates to the issue where your function "changes inventory balance of all items"?

Comment: that is a direct problem. I fully understand the logic behind it, but fixing it is the issue. I do not know how to tell a[i].inventory which i I'm refering too. Before posting it here I tried without for-loop but it just exits the program.

Comment: A for-loop iterates over a range of values. In your case, you don't want to do that. You already called your search function and presumably are now storing its return value, which is the index you want to modify. So use that index. There is no need for a loop at all.

Comment: I fixed it now by removing for-loop and it worked, but do not know if it is the right way. EDIT: saw your comment now, then it is right I gues, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
void changeIn(Car a[], int n)
{
  int input;
  int i;
  searchIt(a, i);
```

passes an uninitialized register-length to `searchIt()`, probably causing it to go *way* out of bounds. Then it throws away the return value of `searchIt()`, and then uses the still uninitialized `i` to index into the array. Not good. It should be:

```
void changeIn(Car a[], int n)
{
  int input;
  const int i = searchIt(a, n);
```

Edit:

As you pointed out in a comment, yes the loop in `changeIt()` makes no sense; you don't want to change more than one element so there is no need to loop. Looping is for expressing repetition and there's no need for that here.

It should just be:

```
    a[i].inventory += input;
    if (a[i].inventory < 0)
        a[i].inventory = 0;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still changes values of all elements. I'm thinking maybe the for-loop before a[i].inventory += input; is the problem.